# iPhone app development. How does an app like snapchat send data from user to user?

Tags: ios

I'm just starting to get into app development and have just been learning the uses of Xcode and Objective-C language. Just wondering how an app like snapchat or any other app can send data from one user to another. General answers would suffice just to better my understanding.

1. How do they test this functionality?
2. How can they connect peer to peer and send data from one phone to another? Is it all accessed in one database that the app connects to everytime that it pulls down?
3. When you sign up for an app like this with a registered account is that information stored on the iphone?

Comment: generally speaking, there's no such thing as reliable peer-to-peer between phones. it's not impossible, but not something you rely on. so... everything gets proxied through servers.

Comment: So they setup servers for the app that get accessed every time when you load the app up? Is this something configured into xcode? Or just accessing mysql for example?

Comment: phones can't contact mysql directly either - there's no mysql drivers for android, and you really do NOT want to make your DB server directly accessible via the public internet

Answer (score 1):

1. > How do they test this functionality?

   I would try to do this with real devices, and/or using a network sniffer tool to inspect the send packets.
2. > How can they connect peer to peer and send data from one phone to another? Is it all accessed in one database that the app connects to everytime that it pulls down?

   Someones sends you a snap
   your app will ask the database every ...min or when you reload if there's something new to load, and gets it from the database if there is something new
3. When you sign up for an app like this with a registered account is that information stored on the iphone?

Connect to snapchat
get a snap from someone and wait till you can view it
start airplane mode and see if it loads, if it does there are files (temporarily) stored on your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two ways data can be sent to a device. One is the device polls the main server periodically. This can be seen in a pull to refresh scenario. The other is the server can send a push notification to the specific phone and app which causes the data to be received by the device and displayed however the programmer wants. So device to device is essentially one person sending something through a web service call to your server. Your server them packages that information into a Json payload and sends a push notification to the recipient. It seems like its device to device because its so quick, but it requires that you have a server in the middle and of course your server is really sending the push notification to Apple's push server, so there really are two servers involved.